# Create new record type inline by extending existing record with new member

Tags: generics, types, f#

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39274881/38055) and trying out [this suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39285062/38055), I have the following generic entity type:

```
type Entity<'a> = {
    Id : Guid
    Data : 'a
}
```

Now, before I expose this in an API, I want to flatten it, so that the `Id` and the properties in `Data` can be serialized next to each-other. I tried this, but it doesn't compile:

```
let flatten<'a> (v : Entity<'a>) = { v.Data with Id = v.Id }
```

What I had hoped to achieve, was to return a record type such that if `'a` is e.g. `{ foo : string; bar : int }`, then `flatten { Id  = someGuid; Data = { foo : "baz"; bar : 42 } }` would return `{ Id = someGuid; foo = "baz"; bar = 42 }` (or equivalent).

Is there a way to accomplish this, or am I trying to make the type system too dynamic?

Comment: I think the first example can be done with inline and magic.  Object expressions are close for the second https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions

Comment: What type would `{ Id = someGuid; foo = "baz"; bar = 42 }` have?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I realize that there is no defined type for this, and that's probably why it doesn't work. What I'd like to accomplish is analogous with defining an anonymous type for `{ Id = someGuid; foo = "baz"; bar = 42 }` - and similar anonymous types for other entity types.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Thanks! I'll look into that and see if I can build something from it.

Comment: If there's no type that the return value can fit into, then you can't do it. F# has a Hindley-Milner type system. It's not Clojure...

Comment: At the moment there are no anonymous types in F#, the closer you can get to a generic flatten would require declaring the output types in advance and creating an overload for each one. I can provide you an example if you are interested in this alternative.

Comment: @Gustavo F# *does* have anonymous types; they're called *tuples* ;)

Comment: It's a fair question. The Elm language does have extensible records while keeping everything type checked, allowing you to use records without naming any types, or write functions on records without knowing their types. OCaml also has something similar for discriminated unions (polymorphic variants).

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that there would be any theoretical obstacles for this without restricting F#'s type inference. That is to say, you should in theory be able to statically infer the return type of `flatten<'a>` for any given `'a` as a new (unnamed) record type which has all the fields of `'a`, plus an `Id` field. But - as always - this doesn't at all imply that the feature is implemented (or even desired) in the language :)

Comment: You can vote for [this feature](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5673015-support-c-like-anonymous-types-in-f), at the moment it's under review.

Comment: @MarkSeemann hardly. Tuples are generic bags that loose information about property names i.e. context. Most of the time they are of no use in scenarios like the OP described. To be relevant in web programming, F# needs true anonymous types, like the ones in C#.

Comment: @Infinum: I wouldn't go as far as saying that it's a *requirement* to be relevant. It would make some things easier, but it's very hard for me to judge at what cost. The fact that I and a colleague spent 4-5 hours the other day in a lab session experimenting with Suave and had a total of one (1) runtime errors until we had a well-functioning REST API for one resource, already makes F# a strong contender for my next project...