# Copy and update record expression with generic Types

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have two types, and they share one named value.

```
type Type1 = 
    {
        p1: int;
        p2: int;
    } 
type Type2 = 
    {
        p1 : int;
        p3 : int;
    }
```

Is it possible to create a function that change only this named value (p1) and returns the new record?

I tried and got this far:

```
type IType = 
    abstract member p1: int;

type Type1 = 
    {
        p1: int;
        p2: int;
    } 
    interface IType with
        member this.p1 = this.p1

type Type2 = 
    {
        p1 : int;
        p3 : int;
    }
    interface IType with
        member this.p1 = this.p1

let changeP1ToTen (value: 'a when 'a :> IType) = 
    let newValue = {value with p1 = 10}
    newValue

let type1 = 
    {
        p1 = 50
        p2 = 80
    }
let newType1 = 
    changeP1ToTen(type1)
```

This doesn't work since the compiler assumes that {value with p1 = 10} is Type2 when it could be either.

If there is a better and clever solution it would help too.

I know this is possible if I use mutable for my types or use a class instead of a simple record but I was wondering if there was a better way to deal with it rather than the OO approach.

Comment: The `{ with ... }` syntax is very rigid, it works only with records, and only with records of known types. You may want to look at Lens from [FSharpx.Extras](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Extras/index.html).

Comment: Well, that is pretty bad. I can't see how I can use Lens to solve my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274881/f-type-constraint-for-record-type-with-specific-property

Comment: Guess this can't be solve like this and I will have to look for another solution. 
Records in F# feels to me like it has so much potential but because of the limitations are kinda hard to work with.
Lenses feels like are not worth the trouble, it seems easier to just use classes instead.
Thank guys for the assist.

Comment: I think what u r looking for is usually called "duck typing". u may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065939/f-and-duck-typing

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you could try this...

```
type Type1 =
    {
        p1 : int;
        p2 : int;
    }
type Type2 =
    {
        p1 : int;
        p2 : int;
    }
type Wrapper =
    | TOne of Type1
    | TTwo of Type2

let changeP1ToTen = function
    | TOne of t1 -> { t1 with p1 = 10 }
    | TTwo of t2 -> { t2 with p1 = 10 }

let type1 = { p1 = 50; p2 = 80 }

// Requires extra wrapping step, is that a dealbreaker?
let newtype1 = TOne type1 |> changeP1ToTen

// If that's a problem for ya, here's a function to fix it
let iTypeToWrapper (value: 'a when 'a :> IType) =
    match value with
        | :? Type1 as t1 -> TOne t1
        | :? Type2 as t2 -> TTwo t2

let othernewtype1 = iTypeToWrapper type1 |> changeP1ToTen
```

The problem with the iTypeToWrapper function is that it will fail if you pass in something other than a `Type1` or `Type2`.  To fix this, you can use the following, if using optionals is acceptable for your use case.

```
// val iTypeToWrapper : ('a when 'a :> IType) -> Wrapper option
let iTypeToWrapper (value: 'a when 'a :> IType) =
    match value with
        | :? Type1 as t1 -> TOne t1 |> Some
        | :? Type2 as t2 -> TTwo t2 |> Some
        | _ -> None
```